# How to add new slide while copying excel tables using "for" loop from Excel vba?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

```
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim shp As Object
Dim MySlideArray As Variant
Dim MyRangeArray As Variant
Dim x As Long

PowerPointApp.ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation

MySlideArray = Array(1, 2)
MyRangeArray = Array(Worksheets("name").Range("A3:E17"), Worksheets("age").Range("A22:E37"))

For x = LBound(MySlideArray) To UBound(MySlideArray)
    MyRangeArray(x).Copy
    Set shp = myPresentation.Slides(MySlideArray(x)).Shapes.PasteSpecial(DataType:=2)
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.AddSlide(PowerPointApp.Slides.Count + 1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank).Select

Next x
```

Question 1) The error is "Object doesn't support this prop or method" just at the `Count+1.select` line. What is my mistake?

Question 2) If i have two ranges of cells "A1:E9" and "A11:E20" in **same** sheet that i want to paste in **same** slide, is there a way to write code which looks for non-empty cells from A1 and copies data till the last filled row and paste in powerpoint?

Apologies for the long question. Will be happy to get any answer.

Comment: You've already `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation`... why are you trying to `Set myPresentation = ` again? `Set mySlide = myPresentation.AddSlide(myPresentation.Slides.Count + 1...`

Comment: @BigBen - i tried your cmd and still the error persists. `mySlide` or `myPresentation` are both objects which have the property `addslide`. I don't get reason for the run-time error 438.

Comment: Sorry - my bad - it's [`Slides.AddSlide`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.addslide) so should be `myPresentation.Slides.AddSlide`.

Comment: There's several issues with that line.... writing up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation.AddSlide(PowerPointApp.Slides.Count + 1, PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank).Select`

There's a couple things wrong with this:

1. You already `Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation` previously. I think you meant `mySlide`.
2. `PowerPointApp.ActivePresentation` - use `myPresentation`, this is redundant.
3. The method is [`Slides.AddSlide`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/powerpoint.slides.addslide), not `Application.AddSlide` or `Presentation.AddSlide`.
4. ...but you want `Slides.Add` since `AddSlide` takes a `CustomLayout` as its second parameter.
5. `PowerPointApp.Slides.Count` - there's no `Slides` property of the application; that should be `myPresentation.Slides.Count`.
6. `PowerPoint.PpSlideLayout.ppLayoutBlank` - note that this *early-binding*, while the rest of your code uses *late-binding*. (`Dim myPresentation As Object`,  `Dim mySlide As Object`, etc.). Best to be consistent. I've laid out an early-binding approach

With those revisions:

```
Const ppLayoutBlank as Long = 12

With myPresentation.Slides
    Set mySlide = .Add(.Count + 1, ppLayoutBlank)
End With
```

Comment: @SatvikK - [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) may help with Question 2, but I'm not sure I understand exactly what the end goal is... it might be easier to ask a new question.

Comment: i have posted my question here. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61022610/13119116. Thanks in advance.